# Debugging lapply/sapply calls

Tags: r

Code written using lapply and friends is usually easier on the eyes and more Rish than loops.  I love lapply just as much as the next guy, but how do I debug it when things go wrong? For example:

```
> ## a list composed of numeric elements 
> x <- as.list(-2:2)
> ## turn one of the elements into characters
> x[[2]] <- "what?!?"
> 
> ## using sapply
> sapply(x, function(x) 1/x)
Error in 1/x : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

Had I used a  for loop:

```
> y <- rep(NA, length(x))
> for (i in 1:length(x)) {
+     y[i] <-  1/x[[i]]
+ }
Error in 1/x[[i]] : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

But I would know where the error happened:

```
> i
[1] 2
```

What should I do when using lapply/sapply?

Comment: This may be an unpopular response, but after 15 years of R development I've almost always found it easier to, temporarily, convert to a for loop to find the edge case that's breaking my code. Also, starting with a for loop instead of an sapply/lapply can simplify your initial process (you can refactor your code for speed/performance when it matters - but first it needs to work!)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Use the standard R debugging techniques to stop exactly when the error occurs:

```
options(error = browser)
```

or

```
options(error = recover)
```

When done, revert to standard behaviour:

```
options(error = NULL)
```

Answer (score 27):

If you wrap your inner function with a try() statement, you get more information:

```
> sapply(x, function(x) try(1/x))
Error in 1/x : non-numeric argument to binary operator
[1] "-0.5"                                                    
[2] "Error in 1/x : non-numeric argument to binary operator\n"
[3] "Inf"                                                     
[4] "1"                                                       
[5] "0.5"
```

In this case, you can see which index fails.

Answer (score 9):

Use the plyr package, with `.inform = TRUE`:

```
library(plyr)
laply(x, function(x) 1/x, .inform = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 3):

Like geoffjentry said:

```
> sapply(x, function(x) {
  res <- tryCatch(1 / x,
                  error=function(e) {
                          cat("Failed on x = ", x, "\n", sep="") ## browser()
                          stop(e)
                        })
})
```

Also, your for loop could be rewritten to be much cleaner (possibly a little slower):

```
> y <- NULL
> for (xi in x)
    y <- c(y, 1 / xi)

Error in 1/xi : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

For loops are slow in R, but unless you really need the speed I'd go with a simple iterative approach over a confusing list comprehension.

If I need to figure out some code on the fly, I'll always go:

```
sapply(x, function(x) {
  browser()
  ...
})
```

And write the code from inside the function so I see what I'm getting.

-- Dan

Comment: Bad call on the for loop.  That will make things **much** slower.

Comment: @hadley ... because the entire array needs to be reallocated (reserve memory, copy old data) in every single loop step :) `y <- numeric(length(x))` should be the fastest way to preallocate.

Answer (score 1):

Using debug or browser isn't a good idea in this case, because it will stop your code so frequently.  Use Try or TryCatch instead, and deal with the situation when it arises.

Answer (score 0):

You can debug() the function, or put a browser() inside the body.  This is only particularly useful if you don't have a gajillion iterations to work through.

Also, I've not personally done this, but I suspect you could put a browser() in as part of a tryCatch(), such that when the error is generated you can use the browser() interface.

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same problem and have tended to make my calls with (l)(m)(s)(t)apply to be functions that I can debug().

So, instead of blah<-sapply(x,function(x){ x+1 })

I'd say,

```
 myfn<-function(x){x+1}
 blah<-sapply(x,function(x){myfn(x)})
```

and use debug(myfn) with options(error=recover).

I also like the advice about sticking print() lines here and there to see what is happening.

Even better is to design a test of myfn(x) that it has to pass and to be sure it passes said test before subjecting it to sapply. I only have patience to to this about half the time.

Comment: Or just `blah<-sapply(x, mfn)`.  And you shouldn't need both `debug` and recover`