# paired t-test crashes apply-loop (edited)

Tags: r, hypothesis-test

**In response to the helpful comments, I have edited the original question (where I had assumed that a for-loop and an apply-loop give different results).**

I am using R to run a large number of 2-group t-tests, using input from a delimited table. Following recommendations from here and elsewhere, I tried either 'for-loops' and 'apply' to accomplish that. For 'normal' t.test, both work nicely and give the same results. However, for a paired t-test, the for-look appears to works while the apply-loop does not. Later, i found out that both loops suffer from the same problem (see below) but the for-loops deals more gracefully with the situation (only one cycle of the loop returns an invalid result) while the apply-loop fails altogether.

My input file looks like this: (the first line is a header line, the data lines have a name, 4 datapoints for group 1 and 4 datapoints for group 2):

```
header g1.1 g1.2 g1.3 g1.4 g2.1 g2.2 g2.3 g2.4
name1  0    0.5  -0.2 -0.2 -0.1 0.4 -0.3 -0.3
name2  23.2 24.4 24.5 27.2 15.5 16.5 17.7 20.0
name3  .....
```

and so on (overall ~50000 lines). The first data line (starting with name19 turned out to be the culprit.

This is the for-loop version that works better (failes on the problematic line but correctly deals with all other lines):

```
table <- read.table('ttest_in.txt',head=1,sep='\t')
for(i in 1:nrow(table)) {
   g1<-as.numeric((table)[i,2:5])
   g2<-as.numeric((table)[i,6:9])
   pv <- t.test(g1,g2,paired=TRUE)$p.value
}
```

This is the 'apply' version that causes problems

```
table <- read.table('ttest_in.txt',head=1,sep='\t')
pv.list <- apply(table[,2:9],1,function(x){t.test(x[1:4],x[5:8],paired=TRUE)$p.value})
```

One of the ~50000 data lines is problematic in that the differences of all pairwise comparions are identical, which in a paired t-test results in an undefined p-value (essentially zero). The apply loop crashes with the error 'data are essentially constant'. To me (as an R newbie) it does not seem to be a good idea to crash the entire script just because the t.test doesn't like one piece of data. In the for-loop, this data line also results in an error message but the loop continues and all the other t-tests give correct results.

Did I do something fundamentally wrong? This behaviour a essentially prohibits the usage of apply-loops for this kind of batch analysis. Or is there a standard way to circumvent this problem. Why doesn't the t-test just return something invalid for that particular p-value instead of bailing out?

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example reproducing the error? We probably need more help than you give us above. However, don't do the `as.matrix()` line in the `apply()` version. If `header` is really in the file then you may be getting into trouble there. `apply()` works on a data frame just fine, so you can use `pv.list <- apply(table[, 2:9], 1 ,function(x) { t.test(x[1:4], x[5:8], paired=TRUE)$p.value})` rather than work on the matrix `mat`. Does that fix things?

Comment: To add to Gavin's excellent questions:  try running your `apply` code with `debug` turned on.  Some semi-obvious indexing error may show up.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Gavin's suggestion to skip the as.matrix step simplified the script but did not change anything. I am not familiar with 'debug', I might try this later. Next, I tracked down the culprit line and now i (partially) undestand the problem. I have changed the example file above, it is the first line that causes the problem. I can see why a paired t-test doesn't like these data, but is this reason enough to crash the entire 'apply' loop? Is there anything I can do about this?

Comment: I should add that after understanding the problem, I see that the for-loop also rejected this particular data line. I failed to notice this because the rest of the loop worked fine and the output file looked unconspicous (with just one output line missing)

Comment: Good job doing the back-review.  Can you either edit your question or delete it to reflect your updated problem?

Comment: I have heavily edited the original question. Is this the policy here? On the downside, it makes some of the original comments/answers look weird

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In situations like this, I catch all the warnings and errors and investigate them afterwards, as shown here: [How do I save warnings and errors as output from a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4948361)

You may also find some good ideas here: [How to tell lapply to ignore an error and process the next thing in the list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2589275)

Answer (score 5):

**UPDATE** Since you said that the for-loop ALSO give the error and you want the `apply` version to be more robust, why not simply add a `tryCatch`?

```
pv.list <- apply(table[,2:9],1, function(x) tryCatch( 
  t.test(x[1:4],x[5:8],paired=TRUE)$p.value, error=function(x) NA ))
```

This should return `NA` if the p.value could not be calculated. You could change to another value (e.g. `NULL`, `0` or `Inf`) by editing the error handling function.

**Old Post**

I noted that `t.test` (kind of) gives the error you found when some values are `Inf` (which seems to be a bug):

```
> t.test(1:10, c(rep(1,9), Inf), paired=TRUE)
Error in if (stderr < 10 * .Machine$double.eps * abs(mx)) stop("data are essentially constant") : 
missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

So do you actually get this or does it actually say:

```
Error in t.test: data are essentially constant
```

Still not quite clear why the for-loop works though. But note that in your for-loop you do `as.numeric`, which you don't do in the `apply` case...

Comment: I agree that this behavior is also undesirable (but having Inf in the data is easier to spot than the harmlessly-looking data line causing my problem). It seems that t.test is not suitable for batch processing (or that some more precautions have to be made). BTW, the for-loop also fails for the problematic line but at least continues and deals with all other data lines

Comment: @user900889 - Aha! See my updated answer for a possible solution.

Comment: Why I didn't simply add TryCatch? Because I didn't know that it existed :-). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`t.test(rep(1,4),rep(0,4))`would report the same error. And https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2008-February/154167.html is the answer to deal with 1) zero-variance 2) observation number is not ≥ 1

Comment: sorry, I mean probably it is the zero-variance that make the problem happen, i just raise a simple example for simple notification. I will answer in full

Answer (score 0):

I've run into exactly this problem, using tapply to run a large number of paired t-tests. I use sample size as a guide to remove data that I probably shouldn't be running t-tests on anyways.