# R allow error in lapply

Tags: r

related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2589275/r-how-to-tell-lapply-to-ignore-an-error-and-process-the-next-thing-in-the-list) question. I wanted to build a simple lapply function that will output NULL if an error occur.

my first thought was to do something like

```
lapply_with_error <- function(X,FUN,...){    
    lapply(X,tryCatch({FUN},error=function(e) NULL))
}

tmpfun  <- function(x){
    if (x==9){
        stop("There is something strange in the neiborhood")
    } else {  
        paste0("This is number", x)
    }
    }


tmp <- lapply_with_error(1:10,tmpfun )
```

But tryCatch does not capture the error it seems. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to provide `lapply` with a function:

```
lapply_with_error <- function(X,FUN,...){    
  lapply(X, function(x, ...) tryCatch(FUN(x, ...),
                                      error=function(e) NULL))
}
```

Comment: Nice catch! Many thanks. I wonder how it works though? The function is called but the error is not catched.

Comment: Check the output of `tryCatch({tmpfun},error=function(e) NULL)`. The expression you pass to `tryCatch` doesn't cause an error and is thus returned unchanged.