# why lists requires characters for indexing when they are processed via lapply

Tags: r, debugging, lapply

I have following two code snippets (the difference is just in `names` position):

**1st:**

```
library(zoo)
vec             <- rep(c(rep(5,10), rep(2,10)), 10)
win.size        <- c(2, 4, 5, 10, 20, 30)
vec.avgs        <- lapply(win.size, function(x) { rollapply(vec, width = x,  by = x,  FUN = mean, align = "left") })
names(vec.avgs) <- win.size
vec.rep         <- lapply(as.character(win.size), function(x) { rep(vec.avgs[[x]], each=x) })
names(vec.rep)  <- win.size
res             <- lapply(as.character(win.size), function(x) { cor(vec[1:length(vec.rep[[x]])], vec.rep[[x]]) })
```

**2nd:**

```
library(zoo)
vec             <- rep(c(rep(5,10), rep(2,10)), 10)
win.size        <- c(2, 4, 5, 10, 20, 30)
vec.avgs        <- lapply(win.size, function(x) { rollapply(vec, width = x,  by = x,  FUN = mean, align = "left") })
vec.rep         <- lapply(as.character(win.size), function(x) { rep(vec.avgs[[x]], each=x) })
res             <- lapply(as.character(win.size), function(x) { cor(vec[1:length(vec.rep[[x]])], vec.rep[[x]]) })
names(vec.avgs) <- win.size
names(vec.rep)  <- win.size
```

**1st** is working as expected but the **2nd** throws:

```
Error in cor(vec[1:length(vec.rep[[x]])], vec.rep[[x]]) : 
  supply both 'x' and 'y' or a matrix-like 'x'
```

when it comes to this line:

```
res <- lapply(as.character(win.size), function(x) { cor(vec[1:length(vec.rep[[x]])], vec.rep[[x]]) })
```

The error message is same as if `cor` were called only with one argument e.g.:

```
> cor(vec,)
Error in cor(vec, ) : supply both 'x' and 'y' or a matrix-like 'x'
```

Based on [suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395622/debugging-lapply-sapply-calls) about debugging `apply` functions I've set `options(error = browser)` to see what happens. What is surprising for me is that there is no `x` variable in function context and I cannot move in code (pressing `n` quits `Browse`):

```
> lapply(as.character(win.size), function(x) { cor(vec[1:length(vec.rep[[x]])], vec.rep[[x]]) })
Error in cor(vec[1:length(vec.rep[[x]])], vec.rep[[x]]) : 
  supply both 'x' and 'y' or a matrix-like 'x'
Called from: stop("supply both 'x' and 'y' or a matrix-like 'x'")
Browse[1]> ls()
[1] "vec"      "vec.avgs" "vec.rep"  "win.size"
Browse[1]> x
Error during wrapup: object 'x' not found
Browse[1]> n
>
```

Another surprising thing for me is that **1st** example requires `as.character(win.size)` in both `lapply` functions. So if I rewrite the **1st** code without casting `win.size` to `characters`:

```
vec             <- rep(c(rep(5,10), rep(2,10)), 10)
win.size        <- c(2, 4, 5, 10, 20, 30)
vec.avgs        <- lapply(win.size, function(x) { rollapply(vec, width = x,  by = x,  FUN = mean, align = "left") })
names(vec.avgs) <- win.size
vec.rep         <- lapply(win.size, function(x) { rep(vec.avgs[[x]], each=x) })
names(vec.rep)  <- win.size
res             <- lapply(win.size, function(x) { cor(vec[1:length(vec.rep[[x]])], vec.rep[[x]]) })
```

I get the error:

```
Error in vec.avgs[[x]] : subscript out of bounds
Called from: FUN(X[[i]], ...)
```

when it comes to this line line:

```
vec.rep <- apply(win.size, function(x) { rep(vec.avgs[[x]], each=x) })
```

Setting `options(error = browser)` did not helped again and as previously there is no `x` variable:

```
> lapply(win.size, function(x) { rep(vec.avgs[[x]], each=x) })
Error in vec.avgs[[x]] : subscript out of bounds
Called from: FUN(X[[i]], ...)
Browse[1]> ls()
[1] "vec"      "vec.avgs" "win.size"
Browse[1]> n
>
```

Questions:

1. Why is **1st** example working and **2nd** is not?
2. Is `ls()` showing the function context or whole program or where is my `x` variable?
3. Why is `as.character(win.size)` required in **1st** example?
4. How can I debug those errors and why `n` quits `Browse` mode?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused as to what it is about list indexing that is confusing you. Given an *unnamed* list:

```
l <- list(1:2,1:3,1:4)
> names(l)
NULL
```

Surely, indexing by an integer,

```
l[[2]]
```

gives you the second element of the list, while indexing by a *character*,

```
l[["2"]]
```

attempts to find the list element whose *name* is "2". But the list has no names, so it will return `NULL`.

In your second example your first `lapply` creates an unnamed list and then you try to index it by name. Surely that can't work, right?

The same principle works in reverse. If I do give the list names:

```
> names(l) <- 3:1
> l
$`3`
[1] 1 2

$`2`
[1] 1 2 3

$`1`
[1] 1 2 3 4
```

...now `l[[3]]` is still the third element of the list, but `l[["3"]]` is the element whose *name* is `"3"`, which happens to be the first element.

If these sorts of basic indexing issues are confusing you, some basic R tutorials might be a good place to spend some time.